# How can a computer be hooked up to DSL in multiple rooms?

Tags: dsl

I know nothing about DSL. One of my friends has a modem and computer in one room, and what appear to be a phone jack and maybe a splitter with one end for DSL in another room.

How would getting a computer on the Internet in the second room work? Can he plug something in to the second jack, or will he have to run Ethernet to the room/use a wireless modem?

Comment: first thing to learn about DSL is that you are not getting **DSL**, its aDSL, the ISP's **love** to drop the `a`, because it means you get a higher download than upload. A *True* DSL is a dedicated 1:1 circuit.  I HATE when people call ADSL -> DSL... ;)

Comment: +1 for anger and being technically correct at the same time. Everybody calls it DSL for the most part, besides its just a series of tubes anyway. ;->

Comment: ... that clog when people do online gaming, its those damn poker chips !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have one modem connected to one DSL connection, you would need to have your friend connect a Wireless Router to the modem, then you can share the network connection either wirelessly or use a ethernet cable.

http://www.velocityguide.com/dsl/setup-dsl-with-wireless-router.html

The modem may or may not have a wired and or wireless router built in, you would need to post the model for us to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

That splitter is probably a DSL filter for the phone on one side and an unfiltered jack on the other side for a DSL modem to plug into. It really should be only a single jack filter since you can only have one DSL modem on the line. It may be two filtered jacks, though. It should be labeled.

You will need to use Ethernet or Wi-Fi to add additional computers.

Answer (score -1):

Not really. You can have 2 computers with 2 modems on 1 line. You just have to disconnect 1 while using the other. Have done this for 2 years. WIFI sounds easy but it isn't. It slows down, disconnects and otherwise is a pain. If you want true full speed you paid for use 2 on 1.

Comment: The WiFi reliability in great deal depends on the number of WiFi access points and interferences in the location. Certainly Ethernet is more reliable.